# If a thread is waiting on a console.readline is the thread suspended?

Tags: c#

If a thread is waiting on a console.readline is the thread suspended. If not what is it's state?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a Timeout to Console.ReadLine()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a good way to interact (i.e. wait for user input) with the console on a thread if the user doesn't ever enter information.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline) (and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline/57711#57711)) came up with a way to terminate the input thread by having the readline in a separate process altogether.

Comment: And why for the downvote four and a half years later?

Answer (score 17):

The thread is not suspended. It's blocked on a method call.