# How to give users a certain time to enter something? (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, performance, timeout

I'm making a speed game in VB.Net (Console Application) and users have a certain time to press a certain key. So how can I give the Console.ReadKey function a timeout without just waiting until a key was pressed?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline

Answer (score 1):

You should use a timer.  When the user selects the correct key you can disable it.  If the user is to then choose a different key you can just reset it.