# Console.ReadLine Break

Tags: c#, console, sleep

I'm trying to figure out how I can use Console.ReadLine and a timer.  My console program is designed to run a long process automatically, with this process restarting every 30 seconds after the previous process completed.  I want to give the user the ability to break the auto-run by typing a command though.  If I use Console.ReadLine() though, it will wait until the user enters something, whereas I want the program to continue on through a loop if nothing is entered within 30 seconds. . .  Any thoughts??

For example:

> RunProcess > Wait 30s for User Input.  If none: Continue Loop

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a Timeout to Console.ReadLine()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could run your timer on a separate thread. When the user enters text, store it in a variable that is accessible to both threads. When the timer ticks, see if anything is entered and continue accordingly.

Be sure to be thread safe :-)

**EDIT:**

You can use a [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) to tick every 30 seconds and in its callback method, check if the text has been set.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to do that? I haven't really done much with explicitly starting threads etc, beyond background workers. I thought a background worker, but don't know if I can use that one a timer....

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `Console.ReadLine()` but check if `Console.KeyAvailable` is true and then read `Console.ReadKey()` to check for exit condition.

Try this example code

```
class Program
{
    static bool done;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 0;            
        done = false;
        while (!done)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            count++;
            Console.WriteLine("Calculation #" + count.ToString());
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                {
                    done = true;
                }
            }                                
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("end");
    }
}
```