# c# - key input to string or list / deleting last character of string

Tags: c#, console, passwords

Basically, Im creating a basic password script.

The problem im currently having is within registering backspaces to delete characters. I have the foundation to detect backspaces but they dont actually do anything yet because im currently using the input as a string and strings cannot use simple modification to delete the last character as far as im aware?

The secondary problem which leads from this is console "*" characters replacing the true characters are not removed from the console when backspace is executed. Is there a way to modify the console display to DO remove it?

On the other hand if there is a way to delete a single character from a string that would be helpful to know for this program and others in future.

So in this scenario is it ideal for me to insert the inputted characters into a list and if backspace is implemented to delete the last indexed list element?

The code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MobileApplication
{
    public class Password
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                String b = "\n---------\n";
                String Pass = "TS";
                String passin = "";
                int count = 1;
                int limit = 4;

                Console.Write($"{b}- Login -{b}\n(Case senitive)");
                Console.Write($"\nPassword > ");
                while ( count <= limit) {
                    var key = System.Console.ReadKey(true);

                    //if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) {              // the below can be substituted for this but then backspage shows up as *

                    if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.A || key.Key == ConsoleKey.B || key.Key == ConsoleKey.C || key.Key == ConsoleKey.D ||
                        key.Key == ConsoleKey.E || key.Key == ConsoleKey.F || key.Key == ConsoleKey.G || key.Key == ConsoleKey.H ||
                        key.Key == ConsoleKey.I || key.Key == ConsoleKey.J || key.Key == ConsoleKey.K || key.Key == ConsoleKey.L ||
                        key.Key == ConsoleKey.M || key.Key == ConsoleKey.N || key.Key == ConsoleKey.O || key.Key == ConsoleKey.P||
                        key.Key == ConsoleKey.Q || key.Key == ConsoleKey.R || key.Key == ConsoleKey.S || key.Key == ConsoleKey.T ||
                        key.Key == ConsoleKey.U || key.Key == ConsoleKey.V || key.Key == ConsoleKey.W || key.Key == ConsoleKey.X ||
                        key.Key == ConsoleKey.Y || key.Key == ConsoleKey.Z)
                    {

                        passin += key.KeyChar;
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                   //  else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)    // this is the problem
                    // {
                   //     String temppass = passin;
                  //      passin -= key.KeyChar;
                   //  }
                    else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"\n{passin} ENTER");
                        //break;
                        if (passin == Pass)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("success haxer");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            passin = "";
                            Console.Write($"incorrect password ({count} / {limit})\n\nPassword > ");
                            count++;
                        }

                    }
                }
                Console.Write($"U Failed 2 haxing");
                Console.Write($"{b}\n- Goodbye -\n{b}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove the "*" from the screen - `Console.Write("\b \b")` should handle that.
then remove the char form the string, you can just use the remove function from string.
so the code would be something like this:

```
else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)    // this is the problem
{
    Console.Write("\b \b");
    passin = passin.Remove(passin.Length - 1, 1);
}
```