# Stoppable console reading on different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, console

Does anybody know how to stop the Console.ReadLine method, when it's running on a different thread?

Right now I use a code (the loop part of it) that works like this:

```
while (true)
{
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable) Thread.Sleep(100);
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It does work, but the problem is that as soon as I type a single character, the server won't shutdown.

Does anybody know how to achieve this? (Completely different approaches welcome too, as long as it allows me to read console lines, after I call a Start() method, and that it stops after a Stop() method call.)

Comment: This is a very old question. Yet if you came across this question as I did check out my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49511467/1729973

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the IsBackground property to true for the thread that is running this loop. That should allow the CLR to shutdown the application cleanly.

Comment: I don't want to shutdown the application, I want to stop the reading. And I know about the IsBackground property, but does it work for aborting too? Or only for shutting down?

Answer (score 3):

`Console.ReadLine` calls `TextReader.ReadLine` internally.  This exits if the underlying stream is closed.  If you call `Console.In.Close()` from the main thread it might work or you may not be able to close the console input stream.  Try it and see.

Forget it, Console.In.Close() seems to be a no-op.

**Update**

This post has all sorts of methods for doing something very similar: [How to add a Timeout to Console.ReadLine()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline/)

(Deleted code because it didn't work)

**Another update**

I did some more research and this is what I found:

- The console is in line mode.
- The user cannot enter text in line mode until Read, ReadLine or Peek has been called.
- Read, ReadLine and Peek block until the user has pressed Enter.
- Hence we cannot let the console handle line input or we get the blocking problem.
- So we must use KeyAvailable and ReadKey and manage deletions, etc. ourselves

This article has an example of handling ReadKey input: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.keychar.aspx

If you amend this function to always call KeyAvailable before calling ReadKey and sleep briefly if there's no input you can avoid blocking.

Comment: Tried that, but I wouldn't know how to restart it then... Do you know?

Comment: If you want one thread to detach from Console.In and another to start and reattach, how are you going to synchronize the input?  If the first server had read part of a line, the second server wouldn't see it.

Comment: No I mean, it's for a server, and you can only input data on certain moments.

Comment: Am I right in saying that you don't actually need the input on a separate thread; you're just looking for an interruptible wait on console input?

Comment: There are a whole bunch of approaches for doing that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline/

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's also reading key by key, I want to read a line.

Answer (score 1):

Use KeyAvailable and ReadKey instead of ReadLine. Or possibly call Thread.Abort on the console consumer thread.

Comment: Tried that, and stored it to a list, then converted it to a string. Didn't work too well, backspace crashes, so could you supply me with a working example of that?