# How to have a c# console application wait (synchronously) for user input (ReadKey/ReadLine) for a duration?

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I have a console application that runs automated procedures on a server.  However, there are routines that may require user input.  Is there a way to have the console wait for user input for a set amount of time?  If there is no user input, proceed with execution, but if there is input, then process accordingly.

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That was quite a tough one!  However I'm bored and like a challenge :D  Try this out...

```
class Program
{
    private static DateTime userInputTimeout;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        userInputTimeout = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30); // users have 30 seconds before automated procedures begin
        Thread userInputThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoUserInput));
        userInputThread.Start();

        while (DateTime.Now < userInputTimeout)
            Thread.Sleep(500);

        userInputThread.Abort();
        userInputThread.Join();

        DoAutomatedProcedures();
    }

    private static void DoUserInput()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User input ends at " + userInputTimeout.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Type a command and press return to execute");

            string command = string.Empty;
            while ((command = Console.ReadLine()) != string.Empty)
                ProcessUserCommand(command);

            Console.WriteLine("User input ended");
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
        }
    }

    private static void ProcessUserCommand(string command)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Executing command '{0}'",  command));
    }

    private static void DoAutomatedProcedures()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting automated procedures");
        //TODO: enter automated code in here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Phil!  I thought that there would be a more simplistic solution already built-in.  Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Gabe, what is the problem?  Try putting a breakpoint on the DoAutomatedProcedures(); call.  What it *should* be doing is allow you to input commands (which it repeats to the console) for 30 seconds.  At which point it calls DoAutomatedProcedures (which does nothing).

Comment: AgentFire, how about an explanation on why Thread.Abort is completely wrong to use?

Answer (score 2):

This is suprisingly difficult: You have to start a new thread, do the ReadLine on this new thread, on the main thread wait with timeout for the new thread to finish, if not abort it.

Comment: Even using another thread doesn't work. Aborting the thread doesn't cancel the I/O.