# How can I send keys to background process?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

Using C# I would like to send CTRL+C (break) to a certain console process that I'm running from a service (background process) as it seems the only valid way of terminating it.

How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9016250/922198

Comment: My process has no windows as it runs from a service - or is that a mistake by my end?

Comment: Do you use the Process class? Beacuse then you can can call the Kill() method. Otherway sending "exit\n" doesn't work?

Comment: Killing it usually brings down the graphic driver, the right way is using CTRL+C.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple WCF service to your console application which has a single method:
public void Kill()

In the master service you will have a client of that service which will invoke the "Kill" method when necessary.
in the implementation of that Kill() method, you can call
System.Exit() or do any other shutdown actions your background process requires.

Comment: The process I'm running is a closed EXE file, I can't modify it.