# Adding a timeout to a process in a console application

Tags: c#, .net, excel, timeout, console-application

I wrote a console application that finds some Excel files, opens them up and refreshes the data. Once in awhile Excel will crash or hang and I want to be able to be able to skip that file and keep going on to the next file. I think that setting a timeout that kicks in after a few minutes and moves on to the next file.

I saw this question: [How to add a Timeout to Console.ReadLine()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline) but I'm not sure that it's the right answer.

Here's some pseudocode of what I'm thinking:

```
Set timeout variable
Refresh file
If timeout has been exceeded, go to the next file.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try a backgroundworker with supports cancellation.  But if it is hung in Excel then you might not get a chance to read the cancellation pending.

Comment: That's probably what I'm looking for, although you're probably right about Excel being hung... Crap. Thanks though.

Comment: Can you use OleDb to read the Excel files?  That might be more stable than actually opening Excel itself.