# How do I wait for console input like 2 seconds?

Tags: c#, console, console-application, readline

The whole Idea is that I give the player 2 seconds to type Dodge or Attack.
If they havent typed Dodge or Attack they die.
I cant figure out how to break out of the ReadLine.
I someone can help me thanks.
(C# Console Application)

Comment: i'm not so familiar with C# but you can't just set an interval like; `Interval = 2000`;

Answer (score 0):

Note that reading from Console is no different that reading from a file, or another stream.

You will have to use threads.

Details here: [How to add a Timeout to Console.ReadLine()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline)

EDIT: Make sure to have `using System.Threading` if you use that answer.

Comment: You're supposed to flag (or vote to close) as a duplicate, not post an answer linking to the duplicate.

Comment: I cannot vote to close.

Comment: I tried that one but it didnt seem to work for me

Comment: @Stijn, that is twice you've told me I can flag.

Comment: Does are errors:
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Thread' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)