# Console ReadKey timeout

Tags: c#

I have built a simple console application, and I need to give a specific time for user to input a keychar.

Should I use this?

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

For those who didn't understand, I need the program to skip the `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;` after `x` seconds.

Is this possible?

Comment: Use a timer. Sleep will freeze your gui.

Comment: This answer might be what you need . . . http://stackoverflow.com/a/57655/18797

Comment: @OndrejJanacek What is the console GUI?

Comment: @Tony "main loop" is clearly i think

Comment: Flagged as not a duplicate of the highlighted question, though is related and some of the answers there are actually for this question. I searched out this question understanding that Console.ReadKey and Console.ReadLine were too functionally different for a single solution in all scenarios and as such warrant distinction.

Answer (score 22):

I would do it like this:

```
DateTime beginWait = DateTime.Now;
while (!Console.KeyAvailable && DateTime.Now.Subtract(beginWait).TotalSeconds < 5)
    Thread.Sleep(250);

if (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    Console.WriteLine("You didn't press anything!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("You pressed: {0}", Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);
```

Comment: as said @OndrejJanacek `Thread.Sleep(250);`  will freeze gui

Comment: yep, because 250 ms markedly less than 1 second, but gui all the same freeze

Comment: @Grundy That's why I used it value. So I believe it solves the problem in this case.

Comment: This is really helpful. The only change I made was to use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch instead of DateTime.Now instead, which let me skip the subraction

Comment: there will be no gui to be frozen. It's console.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** if you use `Thread.Sleep()` to wait for 1 second it hangs the Main Thread for given period of time.

**Solution :**  you can use `System.Timers.Timer` to wait for given amount of time.

Try This:

```
    System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer1.Interval=1000;//one second
    timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Start();
    char ch;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        ch=Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        //stop the timer whenever needed
        //timer1.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: this is not what OP needed, in your solution you call `Console.ReadKey()` periodically, but OP want **skip** _the Console.ReadKey().KeyChar; after x seconds_

Comment: @Grundy: this is not exact solution, as OP just asked `Should I use this? Thread.Sleep()` it answers the question IMO. i would have provided exact solution if he has shown his code.

Comment: OP asked about using it for concrete problem, but in your answer something else