# Print object on screen and move it randomly on c#

Tags: c#, console-application

I am looking to add an object in c# using console application, then once its is on screen i would like to have it move within the bounds of my window to different locations once it has been hit. This is the code i have so far to print the apple on screen.

```
 static void Apple()
        {
            do
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                NewApple = RandApple.Next(200);
                Console.Write("A");
                Console.ReadLine();
            } while (!Gameover);
        }
```

Comment: Console is probably not the best technology choice for accomplishing this. I'm not saying its impossible, but it will likely be ugly. Have you considered using a different tech, like WPF or XNA that is better for canvas style drawing?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: No! Give us the old-skool console games!

Comment: I am practicing with c# console commands for a course i am on. This has been racking my brain for a while now. i can do random positions but not move the character. Its a pretty basic game.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [`Console.SetCursorPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

In that way you can move the cursor to any place on the screen:

```
Random random = new Random();
Console.SetCursorPosition(random.Next(10), random.Next(10));
Console.Write("X");
```

Where 10 is the maximum size of your array [10,10].

Comment: I have that set up to put it in location but i would not like to write 40- 100 lines of code just to move it around the screen, any other advice?

Comment: @BamBam: I see only two lines of code. Can you explain your problem a little more. Not sure if I understand you correctly.

Comment: I am looking to move it to a random location once the apple has been eaten but keep within the bounds of my grid array.

Comment: Then calculate X and Y according to your grid. Is that the problem?

Comment: Exactly that, i think i can get the Y values but never the X.

Comment: So you have to calculate a 100% random place on the screen? Or are there more rules?

Comment: other then it changing locations once eaten nope, pretty sure that is all.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`Random.Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: i have tried something like that but it did not work when i placed it.

Comment: okay so i tried the code but i cant seem to get it to register while my game is active. i also do not know how to check its position with the snakes position so that i can execute the random function. know anything that would help ?

Comment: @BamBam: I think your ReadLine is blocking. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2041489/993547) how to overcome this (it's not that straight forward). At timeout you can do the actual move.

Comment: No that wouldn't work i would need to repeat the code every time i wanted to use the instance.