# how to close console window automatically after console.readline() in C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, console-application, console.readline

I have a console application which does some process and shows some success and failure messages at the end with Console.Readline();

Once the user see those messages, lets say in 10 seconds I want to close the console window automatically but that does not happen.

I tried return, Environemnt.Exit(0) but console does not close.

I don't the use to press some key, is there any way to close the console window automatically.

It's a .NET 4.0 based console application

Comment: are you using ReadLine just for stopping purposes, or do you really need user input?

Comment: I am using console.readline() to display the status messages from Console.Writeline() --- readline purpose is only to display those messages on the console

Comment: Are you running your console application by double-clicking the icon, or by invoking it textually from an already open console window?

Comment: its a scheduled task...runs automatically at scheduled time from task scheduler

Comment: I don't quite get why are you using Console.ReadLine(), could you explain please?

Comment: In summary you are using Console.ReadLine() but you don't want the user to have to press some key?   ConsoleReadLine() does not display messages.

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline). That should do what you're seeking.

Comment: If you have a set interval that you want to wait, why even call Console.Readline()? Why not just Thread.Sleep(10000)?

Comment: @J.Wells, thank you.. I simply used thread.sleep... it solved my purpose.!!

Comment: Np! I'll post as an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Thread.Sleep(10000);` will delay execution of the current thread for 10 seconds, then continue, eliminating the need to call `Console.Readline()`.