# How to use AutoResetEvent in WinForms

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, autoresetevent

I recently found out about messaging between `Threads` in my application using `AutoResetEvent`. In a console app I would make a `while(true)` loop and rely on `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne()` to wait for a thread to signal that e.g. data is ready to be processed with `AutoResetEvent.Set()`. I know how to share data between threads using a `Class` that has a method for the worker thread, and data elements to share between the worker thread and the main thread.

My question is how to utilize `AutoResetEvent` in a Winforms app, where I normally don't see a command loop. Where should I put the `WaitOne()` call in a Winforms app?

About sample code: the best example is an [answer on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18342182/1845672) about how to make a `Console.ReadLine()` with a timeout, which is basically a straightforward example on how to use `signals`. That example is a console app example.

When googling, the answer on my question might be using the `BackgroundWorker` control ?

Comment: Could you please post a small, yet complete sample of what you're trying to do?

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking about. You can use `AutoResetEvent` in those places, where you need an event for multithreading synchronization, regardless of underlying platform: winforms, WPF, console app or a class library.

Comment: It is the kind of hack you need in a console mode app.  But *not* in a Winforms app, it already solves the producer-consumer problem.  Simply call Control.BeginInvoke() from a worker thread.  Like BackgroundWorker does.

Comment: Answer would be simple - it's different. There is no what you call command loop, but rather message processing loop. `Wait..` can still be used: to wait in other than UI thread or to block UI thread (not recommended). So real question is what you are trying to do (`AutoResetEvent` may be a very wrong solution to your problem).

Comment: OK, if you all tell me that in `WinForm` apps I should use `BackgroundWorker` instead of the `AutoResetEvent` , then my question is very useful, at least for myself. No matter how many people downvote my question without explanation :-)

Comment: The main UI thread of an application is a single-threaded apartement, that has an implied and expected contract of *never waiting*.  You generally never want to use synchronization primitives like events, mutexs, semaphores, etc. on the UI thread.  BackgroundWorker is a *much* better idea.  You might be able to use async/await or `Task`s but you'll need to provide more detail.

Comment: @Roland downvoting on SO is *rarely* tied to usefulness of the question or the answer, unfortunately.  Don't take it personally.

Comment: There are probably thousands of such questions in here, all with the answer 'You must not wait in a GUI event-handler'.

Comment: @MartinJames Right, but my question is not asking for that answer, but on `how` to get the required multithreading done right, or on how to apply multithreading principles that work in a console, in a winform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the complete solution to use multithreading in Winforms is to combine `BackgroundWorker` and `AutoResetEvent`.

If I am correct, then `BackgroundWorker` is like a `Thread`, with the advantage that it interfaces nicely with the `ProgressChanged` event handler for signalling from background thread to UI. We might still need `AutoResetEvent` for the signalling from UI to background thread. In my case, I want to use a Next button to start a new blocking call to receive data. Below is my code that I just tested.

Question is, however, if there really is no better way than using `AutoResetEvent` here. Seems to work great, though.

```
/// <summary>
/// The Next button uses this to signal the BackgroundWorker
/// to start the blocking call to Receive data
/// </summary>
private AutoResetEvent _SignalStartReceive  = new AutoResetEvent(false);

/// <summary>
/// To implement variable time it takes until Receive returns
/// </summary>
private Random _RandomTime = new Random();

// Class Initializer
public Form()
{
    backgroundWorker_Receive.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker_Receive.RunWorkerAsync();
    return;
}

/// <summary>
/// User presses this button when he is ready to Receive the next
/// data packet
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void button_ReceiveNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkBox_Receive.Checked = true;
    textBox_ReceivedContent.Text = "";
    _SignalStartReceive.Set();
    return;
}

/// <summary>
/// User presses this button when he is ready to Receive the next
/// data packet
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void button_ReceiveNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkBox_Receive.Checked = true;
    textBox_ReceivedContent.Text = "";
    _SignalStartReceive.Set();
    return;
}

/// <summary>
/// This is the worker thread, running in the background
/// while the UI stays responsive
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void backgroundWorker_Receive_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    while (true)
    {
        // blocking: wait for button click
        _SignalStartReceive.WaitOne();
        // blocking: wait for datagram over network
#if true //temporary code to simulate UdpClient.Receive()
        DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        int RandomTimeMs = 2000 + 30 * _RandomTime.Next(100);
        Thread.Sleep(RandomTimeMs);
        _ReceivedDatagram = string.Format("UDP data ... {0} ms", (DateTime.Now - StartTime).TotalMilliseconds);
#else
        something with UdpClient.Receive();
#endif
        // succeeded:
        worker.ReportProgress(0);//fire the event: Receive_ProgressChanged (argument does not matter)
    }
    //return; //unreachable, but would fire the Completed event
}

/// <summary>
/// Handler for the ReportProgress() call by the BackgroundWorker Thread
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void backgroundWorker_Receive_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox_ReceivedContent.Text = _ReceivedDatagram;
    checkBox_Receive.Checked = false;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question I understand that your UI thread should wait for an event.

The UI thread of a WinForms application must pass control to the operating system to allow user interaction, so waiting for an `AutoResetEvent` is not suitable. If you want to communicate with the UI thread, you can use:

```
bool ret = (bool)myFormInstance.Invoke(
    new Func<DataClass, bool>(myFormInstance.DoStuff), 
    myData);

public class MyForm : Form
{
    public bool DoStuff(DataClass data)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

You can also use `BeginInvoke` to run code on the UI thread asynchronously.

If you want things the other way around (UI thread tells worker thread to start processing) you can use the `BackgroundWorker` and there should be plenty of tutorials about that.

Comment: Is `Invoke()` in this way easier than using the `BackgroundWorker` control? Does `DoStuff` run in another thread? As the Winform controls are single-threaded, then it would be dificult to set values to labels etc directly from `DoStuff()`.

Comment: `Control.Invoke` makes `DoStuff` run on the thread the control was created on, so from `DoStuff` you can safely update your UI. These calls are queued and executed once the operating system gets control.

Comment: I don't know which one you would consider _easier_ - but you use `BackgroundWorker` to start a background operation, and `Invoke` to notify the UI. They are completely different approaches.

Comment: This solution states that `AutoResetEvent` is not suitable. But in combination with a `BackgroundWorker`, it is entirely suitable.On the other hand, perhaps `Invoke` can be useful too, good explanation. I will try that some day. Thanks, +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `BackgroundWorker` instead.

Comment: In my timezone its time to go home. Tomorrow I will try `BackgroundWorker` and hope to accept your answer.