# Stop a looped thread method after x seconds

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm creating a console game as simple as "I generate a random number, find it", but with many options.

My current code (without what I want here) is availlable on GitHub: https://github.com/crakmaniaque/trouvezmoi

What I want is to create a version of my game which will be timed, so the computer generates numbers, the user finds it, it generates a new one and the player have 90 seconds to find a max lot of random numbers. I can code this easily.

What I will need help is to stop the game (a thread) after 90 seconds and retrieve the number of answers founded from the thread. The `Console.Title` should also show time remaining. The attempt I've tried works, but the thread is not interrupted if console is asking for number input (`Console.ReadLine()`). But the timer is for the entire process, not only user input.

```
private static void timerb()
{
     int t = 90;
     for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++)
     {
         Console.Title = t + " seconds remaining";
         Thread.Sleep(1000);
         t--;
     }
}
private static void cGame()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(timerb);
    t.Start();
    while (t.IsAlive)
    {
        bool good = false;
        int rnd = new Random().Next(0,10); // 0 and 10 are sample 
        while (!good)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a number between x and y >");
                int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (i == rnd)
                {
                    good = true;
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid answer.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know much about threading and at that point I'm stuck.
Can someone help me with my problem? I'm using .NET 2.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a Timeout to Console.ReadLine()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline)

Comment: I've read this topic and actually the timeout here is for only the user imput not all process, validation, etc.

Comment: That's where you have your problem. You said that yourself: *but the thread is not interrupted if console is asking for number input (Console.ReadLine())*. Use the info in that answer to solve your problem.

Comment: Tip: You need to save the starting date/time and check it against the current date/time. Looping and sleeping for one second does not guarantee that you will wake at precisely one second intervals and execute the loop code in zero time.

Comment: Good for date/time, but that is not solving the problem I have.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for a timer?  You could register an event, that would fire after 90 seconds, that would run while the loop is happening. The documentation can be found here: [Timer class MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.80).aspx).

I believe the usage would be:

```
Timer timer = new Timer { Interval = new Timespan (0,1,30);
timer.elapsed += //function to fire to kill the app or the game
```

Comment: I will look into it, thanks a bunch. I will give news if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[You'd need to make each console read with a timeout equal to the amount of time left in the game.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline) That solves that issue.

Then, you need a way to signal the timerb thread to shut down when the main game loop has ended. I think the simplest way would be to end the game loop when the remaining time is <= zero. Alternatively, you could make timerb singnal the main thread to shut down when `t == 0`. Inter-thread communication is always complicated and error-prone, though.

You can signal the timerb thread to shut down by setting a `volatile bool shutdown` to `true` and by making `timerb` poll that variable and shut itself down.