# How to disable user input in C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am building a console application which runs on timer, it is a scheduler SMS sending application the methods are included in main method. How can i make sure that user can't input any character so  that the application continues until the machine stops. Together i want to view the Information regarding the execution of application. I have disabled the close button too. The source code is as follows:

```
public class Program
{
    private const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
    public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition, int wFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), false), SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
        Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 5000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SMS Banking Schedule: " + DateTime.Now);
        DLLSendSMS dllSendSMS = new DLLSendSMS();
        dllSendSMS.GetMessages(null);
        GC.Collect();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why should typed text halt the application ?

Comment: use Console.ReadKey(true)

Comment: Instead of `Console.ReadLine();` why not use a `while(true)` ?

Comment: @Marged I want to make sure that the Console. Writeline message stay active on the Console Display, sometime the user may press Enter or any characters, which results interrupt the execution of the application.

Comment: Your approach is incorrect, it's not a good practice to attempt creating an "unstoppable" application in this way. For example, you tried to disable Close button, but Alt+F4 still closes the window. Consider developing windows service and save your output to the log file.

Comment: Reference this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32532767. I hope this might help you.

Comment: Why a console app and not a Windows service or planned task?

Comment: @SurajS It works. Thanks

Comment: @Guillaume I will prepare upgrade this to Windows Service. Currently this is as per client's requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions of this problem.

1. When you want something to run continuously you should create
   windows service.
2. if you want to change your existing code then try following code. I have added while loop.

   ```
   public class Program
           {
           private const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
           public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

           [DllImport("user32.dll")]
           public static extern int DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition, int wFlags);

           [DllImport("user32.dll")]
           private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

           [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
           private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), false), SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
               Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 5000);

       //Removed readline and added while loop (infinite)
           while(true)
           {
           }


           }

           private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("SMS Banking Schedule: " + DateTime.Now);
               DLLSendSMS dllSendSMS = new DLLSendSMS();
               dllSendSMS.GetMessages(null);
               GC.Collect();
           }

       }
   ```

Comment: What does this while loop do to your CPU utilization ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest building a Windows Service for this purpose, you can ensure it will start (if desired) on machine startup and will run in the background. You can log information to log files, the Event log etc. to ensure everything is working correctly.

Visual Studio has templates for services that make is very easy to build one quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Reference this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32532767/6611487

```
class Writer
{
 public void WriteLine(string myText)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < myText.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            Console.Write(myText.Substring(i, myText.Length - i));
            break;
        }
        Console.Write(myText[i]);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(pauseTime);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
 }
}
```