# How can I call the windows PostMessage function from a worker thread without hanging the console application?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, pinvoke

The issue recreated in code:

```
class Program
{
    private const int VK_ESCAPE = 0x1B;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var hWnd = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
            bool hasSucceeded = PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_ESCAPE, 0);
            return;
        });

        Console.WriteLine("PostMessage works as expected in Debug >> Start Debugging mode.");
        if ((Console.ReadKey()).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        return;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to cancel `Console.ReadKey()` by calling `PostMessage` from a worker thread. This works when I run the code under Debug >> Start Debugging mode.

However, when I run the code under Debug >> Start Without Debugging mode it hangs? Any responses/solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: There could be all kinds of weirdness going on here. Console apps don't really *have* a main window - the console subsystem creates windows but they belong to it rather than to the applications running within.

Comment: As Damien's comment might suggest, if I printout that value of `hWnd` I get a non-zero value when run under the debugger and a 0 value when run without the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Raymond Chen has written a nice blog post titled ["You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). You may want to review this, before continuing with your approach.

Having that said, the immediate issue may be that you must use the [`GetConsoleWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow) function (from Kernel32.dll) to get a handle to your own console window. Because, as other have already commented, your process does not really own the window (it belongs to the associated `conhost.exe` process).

Given that, the following code sort of "works":

```
class Program
{
    private const int VK_ESCAPE = 0x1B;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            bool hasSucceeded = PostMessage(GetConsoleWindow(), WM_KEYDOWN, VK_ESCAPE, 0);
            return;
        });

        Console.WriteLine("PostMessage works as expected in Debug >> Start Debugging mode.");
        if ((Console.ReadKey()).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            return;
    }
}
```

But then, this approach is probably not the right approach to achieve what you want (cancelling a `Console.ReadKey`, as you state).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline) for a way to use a timeout instead.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I've decided to use a timeout mechanism.