# Copying TextReader/Writer to more places

Tags: c#, textreader

I have console application that can turn winform with richtextbox. I want to redirect console and that richtextbox to each other. So whenever I write to them text will copy to another. My problem is when I'm waiting for ReadLine. I would like to react to first ReadLine. This is my code:

```
    class ConsoleFormReDirectWriter : TextWriter
{
    TextWriter t;
    RichTextBox r;
public ConsoleFormReDirectWriter(TextWriter TextWriter, RichTextBox FormOut)
    {
        t = TextWriter;
        r = FormOut;
    }

public override void Write(char value)
    {
        t.Write(value);
        RichTextBoxExtensions.AppendText(r, value +"", Color.White);
    }
    public override void WriteLine(string line)
    {
        t.WriteLine(line);
        RichTextBoxExtensions.AppendText(r, line+"\n", Color.White);
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.Default; }
    }
}

 class ConsoleFormReDirectReader : TextReader
{
    Queue<string> ReadLineQ = new Queue<string>();
    public void AddToReadLineQueue(string s)
    {
        ReadLineQ.Enqueue(s);
    }

    public override string ReadLine()
    {
        string line = "";
        while (true)
        {
            if (ReadLineQ.Count != 0) { line = ReadLineQ.Dequeue(); break; }
        }
        return line;
    }
}
```

Then im handling press enter event on richtext box and apending queue by currentLine. I dont know how to make something similar with console.

or is there a better method of doing same?

PS: i can make new thread that will be asking console for readline in infinite loop, and when readline return something than i can append the queue. But that seems very unefective.

After a while i found semi solution. I used Console.readline with timeout and
now I have my Readline:

```
        public override string ReadLine()
    {
         bool toConsole=false, toUI=false;
         string line = "";
        while (true)
        {
            if (ReadLineQ.Count != 0)
            { line = ReadLineQ.Dequeue();
                toConsole = true;
                break;
            }
            try
            {
                line = DelayReader.ReadLine(50);

            }
            catch(TimeoutException) { continue; }
            toUI = true;
            break;

        }
        if (toConsole) t.WriteLine(line);
        if (toUI) RichTextBoxExtensions.AppendText(r, line + "\n", Color.White);
        return line;
    }
```

And Console.Readline with delay i foun here: [ReadLine(delay)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline)

Comment: Hmmm you could create a custom TextReader that will be a wrapper for [Console.In](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.in(v=vs.110).aspx). By doing that you can add events  that will help you use the same pattern as you did with your RichTextBox.

Comment: The problem is you face that you want to output and input from the same control.  The controls dont use read/write like console does. You would do better to display to one control and accept input in another

Comment: Like lets say always ask for Console.ReadLine and when someone add line to richtextbox then somehow push line toconsole to process it by clasic console.ReadLine ???

Comment: With creating wrapper is problem since Console is static class. and by default Console.In is {System.IO.TextReader.SyncTextReader} which is somehow inicialized and i cant find how.