# No input to the console for a certain period of time

Tags: c#, matrix, time, console

I want to create a function which will return the matrix, but I have a problem with limit the time of put the data to console.

```cs
public static List<List<int>> CreateMatrix()
{
    List<List<int>> matrix = new List<List<int>>();
    List<int> row = new List<int>();

    do
    {    
        row = Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(Console.ReadLine().Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), int.Parse).OfType<int>().ToList();
        matrix.Add(row);
    } while (matrix[0].Count == row.Count);

    return matrix;
}
```

I want to create a loop which will accept the row of numbers, but when nothing is put inside the row at least five seconds for example, then the loop should be break

Comment: See doc on the property,  public static bool KeyAvailable { get; }, on Microsoft's detail documentation site, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.keyavailable?view=net-7.0

Comment: I think you're going to need to add some sort of timeout to the _Console.ReadLine()_ operation, to check for the idle period.  Take a look at this post, which talks about this very topic - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline

Answer (score 0):

Using one of the examples from [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline), I've created a simple example for you which will add items entered on the console to a List collection.  Hopefully it will be a good starting point for you to be able to do what you need.

```
public static void Main()
{
    int waitTimeInSeconds = 10;
    List<string> matrix = new();

    do
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Console.ReadLine);
        var result = Task.WaitAny(new Task[] { task }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitTimeInSeconds)) == 0
            ? task.Result : string.Empty;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
        {
            matrix.Add(result);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    } while (true);

    if (matrix is not null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"# Items Added to Array: {matrix.Count}\n");

        foreach (var m in matrix)
        {
            Console.Write(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Reviewing your code however, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve in your while loop.

Your row variable looks to take the input of the *console.ReadLine()* and convert it to an integer, but you haven't considered if the input isn't of type integer, as if not, it will cause a System.FormatException.

Secondly, it seems like you're returning a list of list simply because that's the type which *Array.ConvertAll().ToList()* returns and you want a to return multiple values. I suspect you just want to return the list of values that you've read from the console instead.

Just some food for thought